# HTTP Protocol Information Leak

Tags: iis, http, iis-7.5, protocol

I have done a test and The result is

HTTP Packet Inspection (Low)back
Port:   http (80/tcp)
Summary:
This test gives some information about the remote HTTP protocol - the version used, whether HTTP Keep-Alive and HTTP pipelining are enabled, etc.

```
Protocol version: HTTP/1.1
SSL: no
Pipelining: yes
Keep-Alive: no
Options allowed: (Not implemented)
Headers:
Content-Type: text/html, charset=UTF-8
Location: https://**********.***/
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 20 Nov 2014 13:35:35 GMT
Content-Length: 151
```

How To fix this issue?

Comment: Fix what issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTTP is ***NOT*** a secure protocol, it never has been, and is not meant to be.

HTTPS **IS** the same protocol over a **secure** channel, though only if you use TLS 1.0 or newer (TLS 1.2 is highly recommended as 1.0 and 1.1 have known issues).